# Preserve focus on closing a modal or flyout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have a question on accessibility.
There are several layers/modals or flyout windows which are opened on click of a button or link.

I will need to preserve the focus on the original element which was clicked to open a modal or popup or flyout once they are closed the focus should be back to the clicked element.

Currently when I tab on the page after closing the modal windows or flyouts, focus starts from begining

i am using angular bootstrap modal and custom flyout windows opened via angular state provider configuration.

Comment: Save the event target from the event that opened the modal/flyout and set focus on that target when the modal/flyout closes. See [MDN HTMLelement Reference - focus method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).

Answer (score 5):

The official recommendation from [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices - Modal Dialog](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#dialog_modal) states:

> When a dialog closes, focus returns to the element that invoked the dialog unless either:
>
> - The invoking element no longer exists. Then, focus is set on another
>     element that provides logical work flow.
> - The work flow design includes the following conditions that can occasionally make focusing a different element a more logical choice:
>
>   1. It is very unlikely users need to immediately re-invoke the dialog.
>   2. The task completed in the dialog is directly related to a subsequent step in the work flow.

To return focus to the element that was focused before your modal opened:

1. Before opening the modal, save a reference to `document.activeElement`.
2. After closing the modal, `focus` the reference to the previous `activeElement`.

Example:

```
let previousActiveElement = document.activeElement;
// Open and close the modal
if (document.body.contains(previousActiveElement)) {
    previousActiveElement.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the above issue by preserving the current focus before opening the modal and restore the focus back when modal is closed

Answer (score 0):

To return focus to the element that was focused before your modal opened:

Before opening the modal, save a reference to document.activeElement.
After closing the modal, focus the reference to the previous activeElement.